# APPCRASH on KERNELBASE.dll Visual Studio 2010 with Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, crash

On Visual Studio 2010, when I just start the program (no need to open any project) then after it's connected to TFS, every time I open a work item, create new work item and then save/close that work item, Visual Studio 2010 Pro will crash. This is on Windows 7 x64. Here's the error log:

Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 10.0.40219.1, time stamp: 0x4d5f2a73
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1116
Exception code: 0xc06d007f
Fault offset: 0x0000c41f
Faulting process id: 0x2374
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf90a75a7f9436
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: a597b2e6-fc9a-11e3-96ea-1803731bb61d

Any idea on how to fix this? I have tried the following:
- reinstall SP1 for VS 2010
- install TFS power tool 
- start Visual Studio in safe mode, resetsettings, resetskippkgs
- start using compatibility mode
- run as administrator
- did sfc /scannow
- do repair on visual studio 2010
- complete uninstall / reinstall visual studio 2010
- install visual studio 2010 SP1 TFS compatibility GDR

Please note I also have Visual Studio 2013 installed on the same machine and working with TFS is not a problem there, only on VS 2010. Any other idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: I cannot see anything related with windows-kernel here

Comment: the error has something to do with kernelbase.dll, but I guess it might not related to windows-kernel, I have removed the tag.

Comment: I finally fixed the problem, after playing around with crash dump, WinDBG, I tried uninstalling Service Pack 1 (http://windows.microsoft.com/uninstallwindows7sp1) and everything works again.

Comment: Wow. That's a very drastic solution. Not very practical seeing how many other software require SP1.

Comment: I read in some other threads that uninstalling and re-installing SP1 works. So it may not be an incompatibility with SP1 causing the crash but rather a corruption in the SP1 install.

Answer (score 0):

I can't guarantee that this will work for your situation but I was having the same crashes and re-installing .Net seems to have fixed them.

I installed .Net 4.5 (which includes 4.0) but I'm sure installing .Net 4.0 alone would work as well.